# Remove page margin/border

Tags: microsoft-word

as you can see from the picture, I marked the borders with X. Basically I've already remove all margin and borders but somehow during print preview, it shows me this white border which is very annoying. I cannot find other way to remove the border. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe those are Print Borders. A lot of printers cannot print to the edge of the paper, so Microsoft has set a minimum distance to always allow everything to be printed. The Print Border is defined by the type of printer you have. If you change your printer to XPS Document Writer, I believe that you can then remove this border.

Comment: Yes you are right, I can see the border is gone when I choose doPDF or XPS Document Writer. But I am going to print it with my KONICA MINOLTA printer only. Even if I first convert to PDF, then print from KONICA MINOLTA, it will still show the borders, are there any workarounds? :(

Comment: If you create a PDF document file, then use Adobe Reader to print, it may get around the problem.

Comment: I've tried but to no success. The border is no longer there in Adobe Reader but when send to printer, it still print out border. Guess I will just bear with it. Thank you by the way.

Comment: Did you change the size adjustment in Adobe from "Shrink Oversize Pages" to "Actual Size" or increase the zoom (say 110%)?

Comment: Yes, indeed I tried 'Fit', 'Actual Size', 'Shrink Oversize Pages' and even 'Custom Scale' but they did not remove the border either. For the customer scale, I set to 105%, I can see the wordings is already move slightly to the left but it is still behind the white border (it is like the border overlap whatever inside the paper if u get what I mean).